# What is a good reference of Frechet spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

I know there is a famous textbook *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions And Kernels* by Treves. Nevertheless this textbook was published in the 1960's and is there any recent references on topological vector spaces, in particular Frechet spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinhold Meise and Dietmar Vogt: *Introduction to Functional Analysis* (Oxford University Press, 1997) contains as well many classical results like the closed range theorem as the modern structure theory of Frechet spaces including a very strong version of the splitting theorem of Vogt and Wagner.